# Does Task.Run() create a new Thread?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, task, task-parallel-library

Does `Task.Run` method start in a new thread or is it still in the thread it was created in?

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{  
    Task <string> test = Task.Run(() => (return "Test"));  
    Console.WriteLine(test.result);  
}
```

Comment: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-6.0): _"Queues the specified work to run on the ThreadPool and returns a task or Task<TResult> handle for that work."_

Comment: Does the *threadpool* create a new thread when something is queued is another question: not usually, unless none are available to do the work and max threads has not been hit. As an aside: you should not call `.Result`, as you may deadlock. Use `await test` instead

Comment: Are you sure that the code you have posted compiles?

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-6.0), we can see

> Queues the specified work to run on the ThreadPool and returns a task
> or Task handle for that work.

As others have said, whole operation just runs on thread pool thread without creating threads for nothing.